# Authorize.net not connecting in Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, payment-methods, omnipay

I'm very lost with the gateway. It seems that Authorize.net is highly supported with Craft Commerce but the gateway isn't working. I had the dummy gateway working perfectly fine so that when I'd go through the whole processes and the order would show up. I put in authorize.net AIM as a new gateway and now when I get to the payment it does nothing at all. I put in this code

```
{% if craft.config.devMode and (craft.session.hasFlash('notice') or craft.session.hasFlash('error')) %}

  {% set noticeFlash = craft.session.getFlash('notice')|join('|') %}
  {% set errorFlash = craft.session.getFlash('error')|join('|') %}

    Notice: [{{  noticeFlash }}]
    Error: [{{  errorFlash }}]

 {% endif %}
```

and I get back

> Error: [Payment method does not exist or is not allowed.]

I've put in the API user and key and the link at the bottom. Am I supposed to set the gateway as default somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is from the cart service when trying to set the payment method ID on the cart during payment.

There are 2 possible reasons the error would appear:

1) The payment ID you are submitting is wrong

```
<input type="hidden" name="paymentMethodId" value="theIDhere"/>
```

2) In the settings (for a correctly submitted payment ID), the "Enabled to select on front-end" setting has been turned off. Screenshot: http://jmp.sh/AxoM1tI You need this on, to allow customers to use the method on checkout.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, looks like we were typing at the same time. I JUST figured this out and thought I'd share. Thanks for the answer though!!